# Need guidance on Magento 2 Develeper Certification Questions

Tags: magento2, certification, associatedevelopercertification

```
Q) You are setting up a brand new Magento installation for a merchant who is migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2.
Keeping in mind upgradability and the need to customize, 
which one do you choose?

A. Create a new Magento instance using composer create-project
B. Clone the magento/magento2 GitHub repository
C. Run php bin/magento setup:migrate <path-to-m1-installation> <new-version> command
D. Create a new Magento instance by using the bin/magento install command


Q)How many shipping addresses may be selected for an order during the
checkout process?

A.One shipping address per line item is possible
B.Only one shipping address per order is possible
c.One shipping address per unit of quantity is possible
D.One shipping address per product type is possible
```

Can anyone please suggest here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that my answers are correct, but this is how I would answer and why:

Q1: answer A - Create a new Magento instance using composer create-project

Just because all the rest options are not correct. Regarding answer B - Cloning repository should not be used when developing a new website. You should use composer installation instead. Regarding C - there is no setup:migrate command. Regarding D - this will not create a new Magento instance, it will only run installation scripts for the new Magento.

Q2: answer C - One shipping address per unit of quantity is possible.

Just because this is how Magento works. For example, you can buy 2 items of Product A and send them to different addresses. To see how it works, you can press 'Check Out with Multiple Addresses' link on the shopping cart page.